# Beautifulsoup issue in finding anchor tag

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to capture a link in my python script.
I have a variable holding the regex pattern.

I want to capture below link from the page HTML.

```
<a class="pg-normal pg-bton" href="/department/office/pg2"> NEXT >> </a>
```

The code is:

```
parser = "lxml" 
next_regex = r'(.*?)NEXT(.*?)'
html_bodySoup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), parser)
links = html_bodySoup.find_all('a', href = re.compile(nextpg_regex))
```

Can't find what is the problem, but it does not give me the link as desired. I tried other more accurate regex patterns as well.

Comment: My plan to use regex was to get the accurate result. Actually I build the regex as : href=(?|"([^"]*?)"|'([^']*?)').*?>(.*?)NEXT(.*?) which somehow failed. Can you help me if there is any issue with this? I used this pattern as next_regex

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the regex here. You can simply check if the `NEXT` is `in` the node text.

You can use

```py
links = html_bodySoup.find_all(lambda x: x.name=='a' and  'NEXT' in x.text)
```

Here, we search for any tag with `a` name and `NEXT` in the node text.

A Python test:

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
html = '<p><a class="pg-normal pg-bton" href="/department/office/pg2"> NEXT >> </a></p>'
parser = "lxml"
html_bodySoup = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
html_bodySoup.find_all(lambda x: x.name=='a' and  'NEXT' in x.text)
# => [<a class="pg-normal pg-bton" href="/department/office/pg2"> NEXT &gt;&gt; </a>]
```

If you want to search for an *exact word* `NEXT`, then you can use a regex like this:

```py
html_bodySoup.find_all(lambda x: x.name=='a' and re.search(r'\bNEXT\b', x.text))
# => [<a class="pg-normal pg-bton" href="/department/office/pg2"> NEXT &gt;&gt; </a>]
```

where `re.search` searches for a match anywhere inside a string and `\bNEXT\b` pattern makes sure the `NEXT` it finds is a whole word (thanks to word boundaries).

Comment: Wiktor, Thanks man! But, if I need to use the RegEx, can you tell me what is wrong with it? Where did I made the mistake? Why because, I am having an image as well for the hyperlink, there I am sure I have to use the RegEx only to get the hyperlink. Thanks!!

Comment: @Varsh You need to tell the regex engine what exactly to apply the regex to. In your case, you wanted to apply the regex to node text, and the node name was `a`. Do the same with all other elements.

Comment: @Varsh Please consider accepting the answer since it worked for your current scenario. If you need more concrete help, with regex or XPath, or CSS selectors, please consider posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use -soup-contains to target that text. It does look like you could probably use just the class however (one of the multi-values). Some options shown below with the most descriptive not commented out:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<a class="pg-normal pg-bton" href="/department/office/pg2"> NEXT >> </a>'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
# soup.select_one('.pg-bton[href*=department]:-soup-contains("NEXT")')
# soup.select_one('.pg-bton')
soup.select_one('.pg-bton[href*=department]:-soup-contains("NEXT")')
```